# Validation loss much lower than training loss. Is my model overfitting or underfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, supervised-learning

I am using a convolutional neural network to train a large set of spectral data, which has 653 classes. I am storing the loss values and the accuracy values per epoch in a list. the optimiser i am using is Adams with a learning rate=0.01. The loss function i am using is a weighted cross entropy loss function, and the test set was made using a leave one out scheme from the training data.
I am normalising the losses by dividing them by number of samples in training and number of samples in validation, respectively.
[image: average loss per sample. blue is validation loss, and red is training loss]

The other outputs i am printing every 5th epoch is as shown below:-
[image: The outputs i am printing out + the graph of the accuracy's, RED-training, blue-validation]

What do you think might be happening here? Overfitting? Underfitting?

Any and every help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow the top graph, but from the bottom graph, you appear to have overfit. In-sample, you get performance near 100% accuracy. Out-of-sample, your performance is around 50%. That's a classic case of overfitting. What is the vertical axis on the top graph, loss function for training (red) and validation (blue)?

Comment: In the top graph, the vertical axis is loss function value over all samples divided by num_samples in training(red) and validation(blue) respectively. I am currently working on changning the way i report the loss function. Early for the training loss function i was reporting it while the dropout layer was active,i.e after model.train(), and now i am doing it after model.eval(). The code is running, so ill write if the that was the case.

Comment: What happens if you don't divide by num_samples? Is blue higher than red?

Comment: my code is still running, but i would assume its gonna be the same. because num_samples in training=9300 and that in validation is 653.